# Python Sort Algorithm

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I am implemented different sorting algorithms in Python to better understand them, and I was wondering what type of sort does Python's built-in sort method implement?

Comment: Great for learning sort algos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's an algorithm called [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) developed by Tim Peters specifically for Python.

Comment: Didn't want to make drastic edits for one character, but it should be "developed" with one 'p'.